# У меня проблема с charом

Tags: c++, c, строки, char

есть вот такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char name[50];
    char names[5][50] = { "ПРЫФЫПФ" };
    name = names[0];
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы я мог в любой момент поменять значение в name на то, которое я хочу, но компилятор выдаёт ошибку: "Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением". Как это можно исправить? Далее я хочу объявить структуру Student и добавить в неё поля Name, second_name и т.д. То есть строки ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОГО размера, const char * name, например, не покатит. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Функция [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) к вашим услугам...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно массив фиксированного размера поместить в структуру. Тогда операция присваивания будет работать. А можно и функцией копирования `strncpy` воспользоваться.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef
struct s50 {
    char s[50];
} s50 ;

int main()
{
    s50 name;
    s50 names[5] = { { "ПРЫФЫПФ" } };

    name = names[0];

    name = ( s50 ) { "ABCDEFGH" } ;

    strncpy(name.s,"123456",50);

 //   system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```